# HERE XYZ cannot upload data files through command line

Tags: csv, here-api

I have been attempting to upload .csv files to HERE XYZ spaces that already exist. I have tried to follow the steps of the madrid air quality tutorial and it fails every time. I have used both regular windows command line as well as linux to see if anything changed to no avail. It just tells me that it could not identify latitude over and over and then tells me the operation failed without giving a reason.I did check the CSV and it does have latitude in the header. I'm not sure what is going wrong ([example of it failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALu3B.png)). I seem to be able to upload .csv files if i don't use a pre-existing space but then i can't add any property flag or anything else you would need a pre-existing space to be able to do. Any insight would be appreciated.[CSV Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov0LR.png)

Comment: Would it be possible to share a sample of your csv file (header + couple lines)? Side note, `--lat latitude --lon longitude` is not necessary since the XYZ CLI looks for typical column names for coordinates, as per https://developer.here.com/tutorials/using-the-xyz-cli/

Comment: Yes of course. I have added a picture of a few lines+header to the question sorry about that. I was following the tutorial that is why i was using the --lat --lon but it is good to know that it is not necessary thank you!

Comment: No worries. I had a look at the extract, and I think that's because some rows don't have coordinates values. Try by filtering out all rows without latitude or longitude and reimporting the output.

Comment: Your dataset is not from https://www.kaggle.com/decide-soluciones/air-quality-madrid/home, correct?

Comment: I will try that thank you! My dataset is from that link it is just the combination of the stations.csv and the madrid2001.csv.

Comment: I tried filtering out the rows without latitude and longitude and that got rid of the 'could not identify latitude' issue but it still says 'operation failed:' without a reason or error code.

Comment: At this point it's hard to say what's going wrong. I can suggest to share the failing csv file, for example through https://send.firefox.com/

Comment: https://send.firefox.com/download/b36ed86dc566f914/#onlENeISWXg-pRKSdTnSYg Here is the link to a .csv i have tried that does not work. It is just a shortened version of the original out file for the madrid air quality tutorial.

Comment: I was able to successfully upload the testout.csv sample using `here xyz upload <space-id> -f ~/Downloads/testout.csv`, both to a newly created space or to a space I already had. Try adding the `-e` option, which is supposed to print data upload errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use below command to upload your csv file.

> **here xyz upload YOUR_SPACE_ID -f /Users/xyz/data.csv**

for more information kindly visit 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/xyz/map_customization_suite_cli_hlp/dev_guide/topics/commands.html